# Exception not working when checking for a null in combobox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to catch an error when a value is not selected in the combobox but I cant find whats wrong. There is a CS0136 error but I'm not sure what to do to fix it!

My Code:

```
        try
        {
            BooksClass.BooksArray[0, 3] = BookCondition.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an item from the list" + e);
            
        }
```

Ive tried using a for loop but the System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error comes up:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BookCondition.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a value for The Book Condition:");
        }
        else
        {
            BooksClass.BooksArray[0, 3] = BookCondition.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Detecting nulls using exception handling is a bad way. Exception catching has a performance penalty. Try not to raise exceptions when you could check if `BookCondition.SelectedItem == null`

Comment: When I use a for loop I have an error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BookCondition.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a value for The Book Condition:");
            }
            else
            {
                BooksClass.BooksArray[0, 3] = BookCondition.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (BookCondition.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a value for The Book Condition:");
    }
    else
    {
        BooksClass.BooksArray[0, 3] = BookCondition.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```